# How can I write three different values(x, y, z) in three columns a text file using Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write three values in a text file using the np.savetext. I tried to do that but when I add two more parameters it gives me an error. But for a single parameter, it works well..

_savetxt_dispatcher() got multiple values for argument 'fmt'

```py
def random_walk_3D(N):
    Nsteps = range(N)
    current_position = (0, 0, 0)
    visited_points = []
    for _ in Nsteps:
        visited_points.append(current_position)
        all_directions = get_possible_directions(current_position)
        not_visited_directions = [direction for direction in all_directions if direction not in visited_points]
        current_position = random.choice(not_visited_directions)

    xp, yp, zp = zip(*visited_points)
    return xp, yp, zp  # returns tuples. If you want lists, just do list(xp), ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x, y, z = random_walk_3D(10)

    print("x", " y ", " z ")

    print(x,y,z) 

    np.savetxt("saw.txt",x,y,z,fmt= '%i') # 
" _savetxt_dispatcher() got multiple values for argument 'fmt'"
```

" _savetxt_dispatcher() got multiple values for argument 'fmt'"

Comment: `savetxt` takes one 2d array as input.

Comment: Why are you even using `numpy` to begin with? You are working with lists/tuples.

Comment: Suppose if I go like this                                                        
     f=open("3D_saw.txt","w+")
    f.write( str(x) + str(y) + str(z) )
    f.close()  . # Then still the result in rows.      (0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1) (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) (0, 0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -3, -4, -4). How can I write this in coloumns.

Comment: Your `zip(*visited_points)` is 'transposing' the list of points into these three `x,y,z` lists.  But if you want 3 columns, why don't you save `visited_points` itself?  That's in  the format you want, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Group them in a list.

```
x, y, z = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(3, 10))
np.savetxt("saw.txt", [x, y, z], fmt="%i")
```

Result:

```
$ cat saw.txt
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
```

Or the tranpose:

```
np.savetxt("saw.txt", [*zip(x, y, z)], fmt="%i")
```

Result:

```
$ cat saw.txt
0 1 1
1 0 0
0 1 1
0 0 0
1 0 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 0 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But I need the values of x,y,z in three columns, not in the rows. I want to plot them.

Comment: @Advaita Amended.